# How to change log level in dataproc serverless spark

Tags: dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

In dataproc serverless, the underlying vm is hidden. How to change log level in dataproc serverless spark?

```
--properties ^@^spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=spark-log4j2.properties \
--files spark-log4j2.properties \
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `file:` prefix worked.

```
--properties ^@^spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:spark-log4j2.properties \
--files spark-log4j2.properties \
```